# Katharsis suppress relationship links?

Tags: java, json-api, katharsis

Is there any way I can suppress relationship links using Katharsis? That is, by default it returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "permissions",
    "attributes": { "permission": "VIEW" },
    "relationships": {
      "grantee": {
        "links": {
        "self": "http...",
        "related": "http..."
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "users",
          "id": "user2"
       }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Which is usually very helpful. But in one case I'd like to return:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "permissions",
    "attributes": { "permission": "VIEW" },
    "relationships": {
      "grantee": {
        "data": {
          "type": "users",
          "id": "user2"
       }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

That is, without the relationship links. According to [JSON API formatting rules](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects), the relationship *must* return one of "links", "data", or "meta" (i.e. links is not required).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the answer is no. You should submit an issue directly so you can get an answer from the team directly.

- I am a maintainer, but only recently so I don't know for sure, but I have wandered around the code enough that it doesn't seem likely